# display custom order fields in a checkout pane of drupal commerce

Tags: commerce

I have added a custom field in orders and I can view and edit. I want to display this custom field in checkout panes, so users can fill them. but by default there is no relation between fields that we can add to checkout panes and the fields that we add to orders.

How can I display fields that I add to orders in the checkout form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Commerce Fieldgroup Panes](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_fieldgroup_panes) module.

> This enables an easy way to collect information in the checkout
>   process... The collected information is auto added to the order... You
>   can watch a demo usage in Commerce module Tuesday videocast:
>   http://www.commerceguys.com/resources/articles/257